# How to run dynamic code in webpack config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had multiple angular directives / filters / services which I want to reuse with webpack. So in general i want to create angular module of some of that files. (always different base on some user input, but this is not issue of this ticket)

I use webpack from my JS file not from webpack.config so it looks like:

```
webpack({
        entry: {
        firstFile: path.resolve(__dirname,'../path/to/firstFile.js'),
        secondFile: path.resolve(__dirname,'..//path/to/secondFile.js')
},
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: 'Path to file to babel',
            }
        ]
    }
}, function(err, stats) {
});
```

So in this specific example i build `bundle.js` from `firstFile.js` and `secondFile.js`

This create bundle without problem but I miss some code here to create a angular.module.

It should contain something like:

```
const ngModuleName = 'myModuleName'
export default ngModuleName
const ngModule = angular.module(ngModuleName, [])
ngModule.directive('firstFile', firstFile)
ngModule.filter('secondFile', secondFile)
```

or alternativly do it same as I do it with static files, so direcly execute just this kind of code without any other entry:

```
import firstFile from '../path/to/firstFile.js'
import secondFilefrom '../path/to/secondFile.js'
const ngModuleName = 'myModuleName'
export default ngModuleName
const ngModule = angular.module(ngModuleName, [])
ngModule.directive('firstFile', firstFile)
ngModule.filter('secondFile', secondFile)
```

Is there a way to execute inside of entry somehow?
Or some other way how to add dynamicly source code to a webpack process?

Thanks for advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's possible to do something I wanted via webpack loaders.

Basically I write my own loader and I use it in `webpack.config` like:

```
{
    test: bin_dir,
    loader: path.resolve(__dirname, 
        "./my-loader.js?"+JSON.stringify(myLoaderSettings))
},
```

And then in my loader I can easily manipulate with source of the entry file. In my case I added new blanked file to entry and add to source what ever I need.

```
module.exports = function myLoader(source) {
    // Source code of existing entry
    console.log(source);
    // Query, in my case it's result of JSON.stringify(myLoaderSettings)
    console.log(this.query);
}
```